# Read empty line in text file

Tags: java, arrays, file, text, is-empty

if I want to read file from text file and store it in an array,each line goes to correct array
this is the text file

111111,34,24.5,first line

222222,53,22.0,second line

333333,,32.0,third line

44444,22,12.6,

if line is empty through exception saying "title is missing" or something like that. 
a code has been made if the array length==4 then display lines in order but if length less than 4  and line is missing throw exception but when I want to put last array[3] gives me error. have a look if you can seethe error that would help

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Itry {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         String [] splitArray = new String[4];  
         String  line = "";  
         String array1, description;
         int number;
         double price;

        // Total sales
         double total = 0;
         Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

        // Allow the user to enter the name of text file that the data is stored in
           System.out.println("This program will try to read data from a text file ");
            System.out.print("Enter the file name: ");
            String filename = keyboard.nextLine();

            Scanner fileReader = null;

            try {
                File Fileobject = new File (filename);
                fileReader  = new Scanner (Fileobject);

                System.out.println("\nTransactions"); 
                System.out.println("================");
                while(fileReader.hasNext())
                {

                    // Contains stock code,Quantity,Price,Description
                    line = fileReader.nextLine();// Read a line of data from text file

                     splitArray = line.split(",");
                    // check to make sure there are 4 parts in splitArray 
                    if(splitArray.length == 4)
                    {
                        // remove spaces
                        splitArray[0] = splitArray[0].trim();
                        splitArray[1] = splitArray[1].trim();
                        splitArray[2] = splitArray[2].trim();
                        splitArray[3] = splitArray[3].trim();

                        // Extract each item into an appropriate
                        // variable
                        try {
                         array1 = splitArray[0];
                         number = Integer.parseInt(splitArray[1]);
                         price = Double.parseDouble(splitArray[2]);
                         description = splitArray[3];
                        // Output item
                        System.out.println("Sold "+String.format("%-5d",  number) +
                                String.format("%-12s", description )+ " at "+"£"+
                                String.format("%-5.2f", price));

                        // Compute total
                        total += number * price;
                        } // end of try
                        catch(NumberFormatException e)
                        {
                        System.out.println("Error: Cannot convert to number");
                        }

                  } //end of if 

                     else if (splitArray[0].length()<1) {
                    try {   splitArray[0] = splitArray[0].trim();
                        System.out.println("  Title is missing "+" "+splitArray[1] +""+splitArray[2]+"");
                    }

                    catch(NumberFormatException e)
                    {
                    System.out.println("Error: Cannot convert to number");
                    }
                     }
                     else   if (splitArray[1].length()<=1) {
                            try {   splitArray[1] = splitArray[1].trim();
                            System.out.println(splitArray[0]+" "+" here is missing " +""+splitArray[2] );

                        }
                        catch(NumberFormatException e)
                        {
                        System.out.println("Error: Cannot convert to number");
                        }}

                     else   if (splitArray[2].length()<=1) {
                            try {   splitArray[2] = splitArray[2].trim();
                            System.out.println(splitArray[0]+" "+splitArray[1] +""+" here is missing "+splitArray[3]);

                            }
                        catch(NumberFormatException e)
                        {
                        System.out.println("Error: Cannot convert to number");
                        }}

                            else    if (splitArray[3].length()<=1) {
                            try {   splitArray[3] = splitArray[3].trim();
                            System.out.println(splitArray[0]+" "+splitArray[1] +""+splitArray[2]+"title is missing");
                        }

                        catch(NumberFormatException e)
                        {
                        System.out.println("Error: Cannot convert to number");
                        }}
                }//end of while
                System.out.printf("\nTotal sales: £"+String.format("%-6.2f", total));

             }// end of try block
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
            {
                System.out.println("Error - File does not exist");          
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: your reference to splitarray[3] is in an else off of if length is 4, so on your last sample line, length is actually 3 and referring to [3] gives you an error. Changing splitArray[3].length()<=1 to splitArray.length>= 4 && splitArray[3].length()<=1 should help prevent the error. To catch the case, though, you would want an else if splitArray.length<4 above it.

Comment: thanks alot I will try it now

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] splitArray = new String[4];
        String line = "";
        String array1, description;
        int number;
        double price;

        // Total sales
        double total = 0;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Allow the user to enter the name of text file that the data is stored in
        System.out.println("This program will try to read data from a text file ");
        System.out.print("Enter the file name: ");
        String filename = keyboard.nextLine();

        Scanner fileReader = null;

        try {
            File Fileobject = new File(filename);
            fileReader = new Scanner(Fileobject);

            System.out.println("\nTransactions");
            System.out.println("================");
            int count = 1;
            while (fileReader.hasNext()) {

                // Contains stock code,Quantity,Price,Description
                line = fileReader.nextLine();// Read a line of data from text file
                try {
                    if (line != null && line.length() > 0) {
                        splitArray = line.split(",");

                        // check to make sure there are 4 parts in splitArray
                        if (splitArray.length == 4) {
                            // remove spaces
                            splitArray[0] = splitArray[0].trim();
                            splitArray[1] = splitArray[1].trim();
                            splitArray[2] = splitArray[2].trim();
                            splitArray[3] = splitArray[3].trim();

                            // Extract each item into an appropriate variable
                            try {
                                array1 = splitArray[0];
                                number = Integer.parseInt(splitArray[1]);
                                price = Double.parseDouble(splitArray[2]);
                                description = splitArray[3];
                                // Output item
                                System.out.println(
                                        "Sold " + String.format("%-5d", number) + String.format("%-12s", description)
                                                + " at " + "£" + String.format("%-5.2f", price));

                                // Compute total
                                total += number * price;
                            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                                System.out.println("Error in line#" + count + ": insufficient/invalid data");
                            }
                        } else {
                            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                                    "Error in line#" + count + ": insufficient/invalid data");
                        }
                    } else {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Line#" + count + " is empty");
                    }
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }

                count++;
            } // end of while
            System.out.printf("\nTotal sales: £" + String.format("%-6.2f", total));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Error - File does not exist");
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
This program will try to read data from a text file 
Enter the file name: data2.txt

Transactions
================
Sold 34   Apple        at £24.50
Line#2 is empty
Sold 53   Mango        at £22.00
Line#4 is empty
Error in line#5: insufficient/invalid data
Line#6 is empty
Error in line#7: insufficient/invalid data

Total sales: £1999.00
```

**Content of data2.txt:**

```
111111,34,24.5,Apple

222222,53,22.0,Mango

333333,,32.0,Orange

44444,22,12.6,
```